# Azure ServiceBus Migration from premium to standard using a devOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureservicebus, cicd, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am trying to create a azure pipeline that I can use to migrate my service bus from standard to premium and vice versa so that I can reduce the cost I mostly use the premium tier only when needed so it will help to save cost if its in standard when not in use more like function app premium and consumption plan concept. I know the consumption plan is not available in service bus is it possible to create like that? if yes can give me an example on how to do that. Thanks in advance

I have implemented it for function apps I need for service bus something similar. I am expecting answer that will give me an clear example from start to end on how to set this up.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to employ someone to do it. Or you oculd post what you tried and what the issue is

Comment: Can't go back and forth between premium and standard. Premium is designed for production workloads and is not intended to be downgraded.

Comment: I am trying to reduce the cost when not in use i will move it to standard plan so that cost will be low and when I am planning to use will move that to premium. It's more like migration is what I am trying. I will have the standard plan with basic cost when using will create a premium plan migrate it. Once done planing to migrate it back to standard and save the cost by deleting the premium.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upgrade from standard to premium and you can use for this azure cli. First you need to follow these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-migrate-standard-premium#migration-steps)

> 1. Create a new premium namespace. You complete the next three steps using the following CLI or Azure portal instructions in this article.
> 2. Pair the standard and premium namespaces to each other.
>
> ```
>  resourceGroup = <resource group for the standard namespace>
>  standardNamespace = <standard namespace to migrate>
>  premiumNamespaceArmId = <Azure Resource Manager ID of the premium namespace to migrate to>
>  postMigrationDnsName = <post migration DNS name entry to access the standard namespace>
> ```
>
> 3. Sync (copy-over) entities from the standard to the premium namespace.
>    `az servicebus migration start --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $standardNamespace --target-namespace $premiumNamespaceArmId --post-migration-name $postMigrationDnsName`
> 4. Commit the migration.
>    `az servicebus migration complete --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $standardNamespace`
> 5. Drain entities in the standard namespace by using the post-migration name of the namespace.
> 6. Delete the standard namespace.

But as far as I see there is no way to go back. So you cannot downgrade from premium to standard. And in fact this is not a upgrade, this is really migration.

Comment: It's not possible to migrate from premium to standard? And delete the premium like you did for standard if not do you know why?

Comment: Technically you can always try to delete and replace, but what abut items already published if you do not migrate them to standard?